# How to sort documents in meteorhacks:aggregate output

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This Meteor server code tries to group documents and sort them by the property "period" ascending but it is not doing it, any idea how to fix it? thx

```
let invoicePopulation = UsageCol.aggregate([
        {
          $match: {
            action: {$in: ['a', 'b', 'c']},
            userId: doc.userId
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: {period: "$period"},
            count: {$sum: 1}
          }
        },
        {
          "$sort" : {
            "period" : 1
          }
        }
      ]);

      //output
      [{"_id":{"period":"42017"},"count":14},{"_id":{"period":"22017"},"count":1},{"_id":{"period":"32017"},"count":271}]

//needs to be 
[{"_id":{"period":"22017"},"count":1},{"_id":{"period":"32017"},"count":271},{"_id":{"period":"42017"},"count":14}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$group` looks strange to me.  Typically you want to group on a specific field and that field would become your `_id` (since the field is now unique).

The way you have it in your code is setting a sub document as the value for `_id`.  If that is truly what you want, then your `$sort` should be this.

```
{
  $sort: {
    "_id.period": 1
  }
}
```

If you are not trying to create an `_id` sub-document, then you should fix your `$group` like this.

```
let invoicePopulation = UsageCol.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      action: {$in: ['a', 'b', 'c']},
      userId: doc.userId
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$period",
      count: {$sum: 1}
    }
  },
  {
    $sort : {
      "period" : 1
    }
  }
]);
```